# Minimal nonnegative combinations of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, linear-programming, convex-cone

**Fact**: Start with $m$ points $u_1,...,u_m\in \mathbb R^n$. Now pick any $u$ in the cone of $u_1,...,u_m$; that is,

$$
u = \sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i u_i  \text{ for some }  \alpha_i \geq 0, \; i = 1,...,m.
$$

Then it is known that there exists nonnegative coefficients $\beta_1,...,\beta_m$ such that
$$
u = \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i u_i.
$$
where at most $n$ coefficients $\beta_1,...,\beta_m$ are nonzero.

This fact is used to prove many things, such as [Caratheodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull)) and the [Shapley-Folkman lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapley%E2%80%93Folkman_lemma). It is sometimes called the "conic Caratheodory's theorem."

I've seen this result in two places, [one](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/jon/Preprints/Books/CUP/CUPold/MaterialI/shapley-folkman.pdf) which says the "proof is in many texts on linear programming" and another which uses Caratheodory's theorem to prove it, which I find circular.

Can someone give me a proof of this fact that doesn't use Caratheodory?

To start, we know that if we drop the nonnegativity constraints on the coefficients, then this is a simple property in linear algebra. Specifically, if $u \in \mathbf{span}(u_1,...,u_m)$ and $m > n$, then $u$ can be written as a linear combination of at most $n$ points in $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$. But it's not obvious to me how to extend this to the ``conic version".